Is QNET 2.0 VTOL Board Underactuated or Fully Actuated?
I'm working on a VTOL aircraft model, but the apparatus available in our lab is the QNET 2.0 VTOL Board.
The help I need is to confirm whether the VTOL Board is underactuated or fully actuated. As you guys have more knowledge and experience with practical systems, so I would greatly value your input. At first glance, it has one actuator, which is the propeller thrust, and one degree of freedom, which is the pitch angle. However, if we observe it in more detail, it also covers vertical displacement.
So, can we say that it is underactuated because it has two degrees of freedom and one degree of actuation? I have also attached a picture showing the equations of motion of the VTOL. Can you please share your insights by looking at this system? Any other thoughts or suggestions you think would be helpful would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and help.


